# Amplitude spectra of cos product

Tags: signal

I have the following signal:

$$\cos(2\pi t) + \cos(2\pi t)*\cos(20\pi t)$$

How would I find the amplitude spectra of this? I know how to find the amplitude spectra of a signal of the form like so:

$$\cos(2\pi ft)$$

But what about a product of 2 cosines?

Comment: Are you familiar with amplitude modulation and its spectrum?

Comment: This is actually from a lab on that very topic. It's the first time I've encountered this so I'm very new

Comment: Do you recognize a carrier and modulation frequency in the product? And what does a generic AM signal look like in the frequency domain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure. Like i said I very new to this. Could I take the fourier transform to find the spectra?

Comment: @codedude  There is a less brute force way to do this.  Use some trigonometry.  What is \$ \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) \$ equal to (in the purely trigonometric sense)?

Comment: ...and yet again a trigonometric identity makes life easier. :)

Comment: What does the text book say that your lab comes from? Surely they're not throwing an exercise on you without theory?

Comment: Nope. It's a AM lab so you're dead on. It's just that it hasn't been taught yet and we're expected to have the prelab done somehow so I'm trying to teach myself the best I can.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities), such as:

$$cos(A) cos(B) = \frac 1 2 (cos(A + B) + cos(A - B))$$

In your case, this woks out to:

$$cos(2\pi t) cos(20\pi t) = \frac 1 2 (cos(2\pi t + 20\pi t) + cos(2\pi t - 20\pi t))$$

$$ = \frac 1 2 (cos(22\pi t) + cos(-18\pi t))$$

Since \$cos(x) = cos(-x)\$, you can also write this as

$$ = \frac 1 2 (cos(22\pi t) + cos(18\pi t))$$

If you factor out the \$2\pi t\$ from each argument, this means that you have two new signals, at 9 Hz and 11 Hz, each half the amplitude of the original signals.

Comment: man I have a hard time remembering all these :)

Comment: Yes, that's why after you go through this exercise a few times, you simply remember that you get the sum and difference freqeuncies of the input signals, at half amplitude.